# Proving connectedness using Hall's theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph. Suppose for every $S\subset V$ with $|S|\leq \frac{|V|}2$ we have $|N_G(S)|>1.5|S|$. Prove $G$ is connected.

I tried this one for a long time and I'm pretty lost. It looks I should be using Hall's theorem somewhere, so I need to figure out what I would like to match. To show connectivity using a matching, I thought of the following bipartite graph - $V_0$ are the vertices of the largest connected components, and $V_1$ are the other connected components. I know there are less than $\frac{|V|}2$ connected components. However, when I try to "contract" the connected components I can no longer verify the conditions of Hall's theorem.

Is my idea way off? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $G$ is not connected, and let $C$ be a smallest component; then $C$ has at most $\frac12|V|$ vertices.

Comment: So after deleting the vertices inside $V$, we have $|V|\leq |N_G(V)|$ and so after deleting the vertices between the other connected components we use Hall's theorem to obtain a contradiction with the fact $C$ is disconnected from the rest of $G$.

Comment: I think I was on the right track, but I should have used common sense and worked with the smallest connected components, so it "needs the least"...

Comment: @combinarcotics: There's no need for Hall's theorem: if $W$ is the vertex set of $C$, $|N_G(W)|>1.5|W|$ implies that $W$ has a neighbor that isn't in $W$, which is impossible.

Comment: Meh :( Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @combinarcotics: You're welcome.

Comment: So $|N_G(W)|>|W|$ would have sufficed as well?